# pytrec library not able to install on my system raising error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, failed-installation

I am trying to install the pytrec_eval library in python and is throwing me the following error

`

```
 pip install pytrec_eval
Collecting pytrec_eval
  Using cached pytrec_eval-0.5.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: pytrec_eval
  DEPRECATION: pytrec_eval is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for pytrec_eval ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pytrec_eval did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      Fetching trec_eval from https://github.com/usnistgov/trec_eval/archive/v9.0.8.tar.gz.
      C:\Users\c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pytrec_eval
      copying py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pytrec_eval
      running build_ext
      building 'pytrec_eval_ext' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pytrec_eval

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

`

I have tried installing the following and rerun the command to no success.

`cmake`
`Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`
`pip install trectools --user`

My system:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.11 and Python 3.11.0 (two different envs failure)
- Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 2):

Accoring to this line:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
> "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

You need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).

Comment: i had installed C++ 17 + . Now i get the error in convert_path
          raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname)
      ValueError: path '/Users/cvangysel/Projects/pytrec_eval/trec_eval/convert_zscores.c' cannot be absolute

Comment: @Kcndze Try `pip install pytrec-eval-terrier`.

Comment: are this libraries same?

Comment: I refer to this issue on [github](https://github.com/cvangysel/pytrec_eval/issues/32) and they solved this ValueError by `pip install pytrec-eval-terrier`.